# Convert JSON properties with under_score to DTO with lowerCamel properties using Gson

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, gson, dto

I'm facing some difficulties while trying to convert JSON response which contains properties with under_score, to DTO with lowerCamelCase properties.

JSON for example:

```
{
      "promoted_by": "",
      "parent": "",
      "caused_by": "jenkins",
      "watch_list": "prod",
      "u_automation": "deep",
      "upon_reject": "cancel"
}
```

DTO for example:

```
@Data
public class TicketDTO {

    private String promotedBy;
    private String parent;
    private String causedBy;
    private String watchList;
    private String uAutomation;
    private String uponReject;
}
```

Mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ITicketMapper {

    default TicketDTO toDTO(JsonObject ticket) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
            .create();

        return gson.fromJson(incident, TicketDTO.class);
    }

}
```

This example is not working of course, I would like to know if it's possible to do this conversion with Gson.

Appriciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html#LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)

> Using this naming policy with Gson will modify the Java Field name from its camel cased form to a lower case field name where each word is separated by an underscore (_).
> Here's a few examples of the form "Java Field Name" ---> "JSON Field Name":

- someFieldName ---> some_field_name
- someFieldName ---> _some_field_name
- aStringField ---> a_string_field
- aURL ---> a_u_r_l

---

```
setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
```

The [UPPER_CAMEL_CASE](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html#UPPER_CAMEL_CASE) is used for different purpose

> Using this naming policy with Gson will ensure that the first "letter" of the Java field name is capitalized when serialized to its JSON form.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Already tried this, get the following error: 
{
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException",
  "message": "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $.promoted_by"
}

Comment: looks like that different error, can you add the error with stack trace in above post ? @user3819295

Comment: That's correct, this issue is not related, I have to validate my JSON response apparently. Thank you very much for your help. if I ignore the problematic fields, it works.